# TabLayout Android, customize background color

Tags: android, background, tabs

in android tutorial there isn't a way for customize tab background. my app is official-tutorial based..can anyone help me with a tutorial or code for backgroundcolor white? 
this is my code:

LauncherActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.launcher);

        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent;  



        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyActivity.class);



        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("myactivity").setIndicator("Activity")

                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, search.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Search"
                          )
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyActivity3.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs"
                          )
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

Launcher.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="[url]http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to change background color of tabs,then here is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{   
      tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); //unselected tab
}
```

for selected tab,

```
tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); // selected tab
```

You can put above lines into a method (say setTabColors()) and call it:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

               setTabColors(tabHost);
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
   if (i != tabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
      .setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.gradiant); // unselectedtab
   } else {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
      .setBackgroundColor(R.color.aquablue);
   }

  }

Comment: @James: thats perfectly fine.. no problem in code.isn't it working for you?

Comment: are you getting error or so...? please post the complete code in as a new question.then i can help you..